# WFFM Create a form by copying an existing one

Tags: wffm

When adding a form to a page in Sitecore, you are presented with a dialog when choosing the datasource of the form. You have the options:

- Create a blank form
- Insert an existing form
- Select a form to copy

My site is in a multi-site instance of Sitecore and I created the site as a copy of another site (including the forms). It seems that [there are problems](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5563/wffm-error-server-cannot-modify-cookies-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-whe) with forms which were copied from other forms without using the WFFM dialog.  What exactly does WFFM do internally when you choose the option "Select a form to copy" is there something other than simply copying the content items in Sitecore?

Comment: What version of Sitecore and WFFM? Many issues have come and gone in the different version of WFFM. Could be an issue with copying forms.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a manual duplication of a form, Save Actions are copied as is.  If you had a Save Action that sent an email with token keys to the fields you asked them to enter, those tokens/guids are hard copied pointers to the previous field items as child items under your 'copied from' form and thus not valid in your new form.

See more details here: [Sitecore WFFM Form Duplication](http://www.nonlinearcreations.com/Digital/how-we-think/articles/2015/05/Web-forms-for-marketers-form-duplication.aspx)

I imagine there are other things affected that their internal pipeline missed in manual duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use custom "smart copy/duplicate" module instead of regular sitecore copy to copy sitecore forms - because in the copied form all the links will point to the previous form - this is not what you want to.
  When you creating a new form using WFFM dialog, it creates the full copy of the form with correct links.

The "smart copy" module could be found at:  [sitecore smart commands](https://github.com/AlenPelin/Sitecore-Smart-Commands)